# Outlook VSTO add-in changing sent item attributes get overwritten by Exchange sync

Tags: outlook, office365, vsto, exchange-server

I have a VSTO Outlook add-in that listens to the Sent Items folder and presents some options for the user to (1) save a copy of the sent item to somewhere (eg to a file system) and (2) apply some attributes to the item in Outlook (eg set the follow-up flag to complete, add text to the subject).

Here's the code - note that the objects passed to this sub are custom objects that contain metadata, notably the `ItemToSave` is a structure that contains the item's GUID, and *isn't* itself a reference to an Outlook object model object.

```
Public Sub CleanUpThisEmail(ByRef item As ItemToSave,
                            ByRef postSaveOptions As PostSaveOptions)

    If item.SaveSuccess = True Then
        Try
            Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(item.GUID)

            ' Stuff to do to the item in Outlook
            With oItem
                If postSaveOptions.FlagCompleted = True Then .FlagStatus = Outlook.OlFlagStatus.olFlagComplete
                If postSaveOptions.AppendToSubject = True Then .Subject = String.Format("{0} {1}", .Subject, DateTimeStringHelper.ParseTextWithDatesAndTimes(postSaveOptions.SubjectAppendOption, DateTime.Now()))
                .Save()
            End With

            item.CleanupSuccess = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            ThisAddIn.log.ErrorFormat("CleanUpThisEmail: Error while applying options and/or deleting email in Outlook: {0}", ex.Message)
            ThisAddIn.log.Error(ex.StackTrace)
            item.CleanupSuccess = False
        End Try

        ThisAddIn.log.InfoFormat("CleanUpThisEmail: Finished processing")
    Else
        ThisAddIn.log.WarnFormat("CleanupThisEmail: Skipping processing of an email that failed to save correctly.")
    End If

End Sub
```

How the above method is called:

1. ThisAddin_Startup() contains the below:

   ```
      ...
      m_olSentFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail)
      m_olSentFolderEvents = m_olSentFolder.Items
      ...
   ```
2. ThisAddin contains a method `Private Sub m_olSentFolderEvents_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) Handles m_olSentFolderEvents.ItemAdd` which parses the info out of the `Item` object, and passes this in a struct to a WPF dialog for the user to make selections.
3. The dialog has a "Save" button, whose event then passes the item struct and the save details to a method on a worker thread within the WPF dialog
4. The worker method calls the "CleanUpThisEmail" method that I've shown.

Some users have reported that the changes to the item in Outlook are being applied, but then apparently a subsequent sync of the item with Exchange overwrites the changes. Some of these users see a message like "you have made changes to a copy of this item...", and the expected changes that my add-in has made are in a previous "version" of the item.

It appears that if the user waits for a little while and *then* applies the options in my add-in, they *are* the latest version and aren't overwritten by the sync with Exchange. Presumably the sync with Exchange has already occurred at this point.

Is there a way I can ensure that changes I make to an item in Outlook are applied in such a way that the Exchange sync recognises them as being the most current version? Seems like I might need to add a wait time on a background thread or something but that seems fragile and inelegant.

Comment: what code do you use now?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev here we go, added code.

Comment: it is not clear when and where the `CleanUpThisEmail` method is called.

Comment: Thanks @EugeneAstafiev you're being very patient. I've added the sequence of calls.

Comment: You need to use the item passed as a parameter to the `ItemAdd` event.

Answer (score 0):

> Some of these users see a message like "you have made changes to a copy of this item..."

That is because of using items in the following way:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(item.GUID)
```

To avoid such warning messages you need to use items passed as parameters to event handlers. For example, the [ItemAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.ItemAdd) event passes an item that has been added to the collection/folder as an argument.

Comment: OK thanks - is it safe to pass the item that I get in the `ItemAdd` event down through downstream methods?

Comment: I gather I can generalise from the linked documentation (which is about VBA) to .net (VSTO) in my case?

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all kinds of applications.

Answer (score 0):

This is a side effect of the way Outlook optimizes the submission process - it hands the message to Exchange and the moves it to the local Sent Items folder. When Exchange finishes the submission, it moves the message to the online replica of the Sent Items folder. Outlook does not sync the two messages since it knows that they are supposed to be the same (at least to the end user). If a change is made later, it will sync the two.
Try to use a timer (use the Timer class from the Forms namespace since it uses the main thread) to update the message later.

Comment: Urgh, a timer? Really? I haven't looked at using the original item (per @Eugene's responses) yet... do you not think that will circumvent this issue?